# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am getting the 'already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first'.  I have enabled MARS but I still get the error.  I'm using SQL server 2005 and I'm doing this from within a report.

Below is my code:

```
insert into [INS Data Collection Files].dbo.[Orders Missing Seats] (INSUser,ordernumber, reference, seat, processdate)

(SELECT    DISTINCT 'FRC16',[INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Queue Detail].OrderNumber, [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Queue Detail].Reference,
                                           [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Serial Parts].PartNumber,  [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Queue Detail].ProcessCompleteTime
FROM         [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Serial Parts] INNER JOIN
                  [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Queue Detail] ON [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Serial Parts].INSUser = [Mes Queue Detail].INSUser AND 
                  [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Serial Parts].SerialNumber = [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Queue Detail].SerialNumber

WHERE     ([mes serial parts].insuser = 'frc16' and [mes queue detail].insuser = 'frc16' and [INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Serial Parts].PartNumber <> '*NOTREQUIRED') 
AND ([INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Serial Parts].ParentSerialNumber = 0) AND 
                  ([Mes Queue Detail].MesQueueName = 'finalver') AND ([Mes Queue Detail].ProcessCompleteTime > '1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM') AND 
                  ([Mes Serial Parts].ActualPartSerialNumber = 0) AND (LEFT([Mes Serial Parts].PartNumber, 3) NOT IN ('3LH', '3RH', '2CT') AND
[INS Data Files].dbo.[Mes Queue Detail].ProcessCompleteTime not in (select processdate from [ins data collection files].dbo.[orders missing seats] )))
```

Comment: Did you enable MARS on the connection string as well?

Comment: Yes I had.  Although I made a change to the report and saved again, which removed MARS.  I believe this should correct my isse.  Thanks!